# Adding JSON to properties in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

I am trying to add and read Json in Google Apps Script properties service. When I log the following code:

```
function addTestCompaniesToProperties() {
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  scriptProperties.deleteProperty("company_list");
  var JsonString = '{ "companies":[{ "company_name":"GE","company_id":"1234"},{"company_name":"Apple","company_id":"5678"}]}'
  
  scriptProperties.setProperty("company_list", JsonString);

  var companyData = scriptProperties.getProperty("company_list");
  var companyJson = JSON.stringify(companyData)
  companyJson = companyJson.replace(/\n/, " ");
  Logger.log(companyJson);

}
```

I get the following log:

```
[20-08-17 09:01:15:886 PDT] "{ \"companies\":[{ \"company_name\":\"GE\",\"company_id\":\"1234\"},{\"company_name\":\"Apple\",\"company_id\":\"5678\"}]}"
```

I can't seem the get rid of the new line characters. What am I doing wrong in retrieving this Json data?

Comment: I don't think you're doing anything wrong.  \ is not a newline character; it's a backslash character, and they're not in your JSON; those are inserted when you log it out because the logger chooses to use `"` to open and close the string, so all the `"` characters inside the string need to be escaped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to escape `\` you should try this instead:

```
companyJson = companyJson.replace(/\\/g, '')
```

or  `companyJson = companyJson.replace(/\\/g, ' ')` .

Comment: That worked thanks. But now I get an error with JSON.parse(companyJson)

Comment: Does this work for you:  `var companyData = scriptProperties.getProperty("company_list");
  var companyJson = companyData.replace(/\\/g, '')
  var parse_companyJson=JSON.parse(companyJson)` @user3511512

Comment: @user3511512 please if it worked for you accept the answer so it will be removed from the unanswered questions feed.

Comment: That worked thanks! One more question, why does JSON.parse convert colons to equal signs?

Comment: @user3511512 I am not sure but you can access it like that: `parse_companyJson['companies']`